# Native: InAppBrowser is not installed or you are running on a browser. Falling back to window.open. on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

InAppBrowser works fine on android but on iOS I get the following error:

```
Native: InAppBrowser is not installed or you are running on a browser. Falling back to window.open.
```

```js
this.inAppBro.create('https://www.google.com', `_blank`);
```

on Android the URL opens fine but on iOS I get the error saying it isn't installed and I'm not sure why.

```
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.0.0",
```

9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
6.0.1

Comment: Any luck resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the build process didn't complete correctly. Build the project again after deleting the `node_modules`, `plugins` & `www` folder in your root project folder. Then run `ionic cordova build ios --prod`

After the successful build, Go to -> `platforms->iOS->"your project name folder"->Plugins` and ensure that `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` folder is present there

Comment: Getting this error after deleting and attempting to build:

An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find module "@ionic/angular-toolkit" from "/Users/anonymous/project/".
See "/private/var/folders/d4/frmmbmss3pn0jvjks1rw83sr0000gn/T/ng-EkKCpy/angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess

Comment: Run npm install command before building. This will download the dependencies in node_modules folder